# Changing asp.net core TagHelpers with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have

```
 <a id="continue-link" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Register" asp-route-id="1">Continue </a>
```

in my asp.net core application, that generate this html when compiled:

```
<a href="/Account/Register/1" id="continue-link">Continue </a>
```

How can i change `asp-route-id` value from javascript? I tried with `$().attr` but it's not recognized.

Comment: Did you try [`$().prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to change your href attribute in generated html.

You can achive this by geting your href attribute, split it into array, then change value in array and join it again into one string with separator and then replace href attribute in your a element.

Code example:

```
var $link = $('#continue-link');
var href = $link.attr('href').split('/');
href[3] = 4; //here you set your new asp-route-id value
$link.attr('href', href.join('/'));
```

Check this [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XKddxN) to see how it work.

Comment: Ah so I was late ;)